# Не могу понять в чем проблема с выводом данных в файл

Tags: c#

Суть задания - записать в файл числовой ряд, затем считать эти данные, заменить в них макс. и мин. элементы на среднее арифметическое отрицательных элементов. Проблема в том, что в конечном файле, вместо нужного средне арифметического числа заменяется на нуль. 
Возможно проблема в цикле, который считает сумму отрицательных чисел, но он вроде как правильный.
Помогите понять ошибку.

```
static public void COUNT(string r, string path)
{
    int c = 0;
    char[] symbols = r.ToCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < symbols.Length; i++)
        if (!char.IsNumber(symbols[i]))
            symbols[i] = ' ';
        else c++;
    if (c > 0) //если счетчик чисел больше нуля (в строке есть числа), то:
    {
        r = new string(symbols);
        while (r.IndexOf("  ") != -1)
            r = r.Replace("  ", " ");
        string[] allnumberstr = r.Split(' ');
        double[] allnumbers = new double[allnumberstr.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < allnumberstr.Length; i++)
            allnumbers[i] = int.Parse(allnumberstr[i]);
        double maxValue = allnumbers.Max();
        double minValue = allnumbers.Min();
        int max = 0, min = 0;
        double sum = 0, k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < allnumbers.Length; i++)
        {
            if (allnumbers[i] < 0)
            {
                sum += allnumbers[i];
                k++;
            }

        }
        double sr = sum / k;
        for (int i = 0; i < allnumbers.Length; i++)
            if (allnumbers[i] == maxValue)
            { max = i; }
        for (int i = 0; i < allnumbers.Length; i++)
            if (allnumbers[i] == minValue)
            { min = i; }
        allnumbers[max] = sr;
        allnumbers[min] = sr;
        double[] b = new double [allnumbers.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < allnumbers.Length; i++)
            b [i] = allnumbers[i];
        string q = string.Join(" ", b);
        using (FileStream fstream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            byte[] array = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(q);
            fstream.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("Текст \'{0}\' записан в файл. ", q, path);
        }
```

Comment: Что-то `sr` нигде не используется. Покажите где Вы выводите среднее арифметическое. А вообще, многовато лишнего кода, попробуйте оставить только тот, [который относится к вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/reprex). Например, если работа с файлами к вопросу не относится, то ее можно убрать, а нужное значение выводить в консоль.

Comment: @default locale, часть где работа с файлами я оставил потому что были подозрения что где-то там ошибка. По сути алгоритм цикла нахождения среднего арифметического правильный, только он по какой-то причине в итоге равняется нулю. Код исправил.

Comment: `string q = string.Join(" ", b);` вот эта переменная у вас чему равна?

Comment: @tym32167 Она равна массиву b, который в свою очередь равен массиву allnumbers

Comment: в ней в вашем случае какая конкретно строка записана?

Comment: @tym32167 в нее записывается строка, которая считывается с файла, он может быть любым числовым. я просто убрал часть кода, где происходит работа с файлами по совету 1-го комментатора.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема вот тут:

```
for (int i = 0; i < symbols.Length; i++)
   if (!char.IsNumber(symbols[i]))
      symbols[i] = ' ';
   else c++;
```

Я понял почему вы это делаете: чтобы убрать вообще все промежуточные знаки между чисел?

Но условие `char.IsNumber` автоматом отсекает знак "-", то есть вы все отрицательные числа делаете положительными, поэтому сумма отрицательных чисел и получается равна 0.

Для разделения можно воспользоваться регулярным выражением:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"[+-]?\d*\.?\d+");
```

В случае, если только целые числа нужны:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"[+-]?\d+");
```

Comment: Точно, в этом проблема. Не подскажете каким образом иначе сделать проверку, что введены только цифры?

Comment: @StonedJes regex с паттерном "[+-]?\d*\.?\d+". Ща допишу пример.

Comment: @StonedJes Regex используешь **вместо** своего разделения. Твоя входная строка `string r`, её и прогоняешь: `Regex.Matches(r, @"[+-]?\d+")`. На выходе получишь [коллекцию Match](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection), где `Match.Value` - это строка готовая к конвертации в число. Тебе не нужны массивы символов, не нужны `Replace("  "," ")`. Ты после Regex сразу приступаешь к шагу с конвертацией в число.

Comment: Все, заработало. Спасибо! Только это не спасло от исключительной ситуации, если пользователь ввел не число, а символ.